# GCP: How to see Stats of Insert, Update and Delete statements in Console or from backend in Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In spanner Console we have QUERY Stats which shows stats of Select queries in Spanner from below tables. But we don't see Stats of Insert, Update and Delete statements in Spanner Console. Neither is that available in below tables

Tables: QUERY_STATS_TOTAL_MINUTE, QUERY_STATS_TOTAL_10MINUTE, QUERY_STATS_TOP_MINUTE, QUERY_STATS_TOP_10MINUTE, QUERY_STATS_TOP_HOUR,QUERY_STATS_TOTAL_HOUR

I tried searching for any related tables but couldn't find them

Can someone please share the list of Spanner tables where we can find Stats of I, U, D statements.

Also, I think it should also be provided by GCP on console for quick analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed those tables and views for DMLs are very useful for troubleshooting but DML Stats (and its backing tables) equivalent to Query Stats are not there yet. I have added this feature request to our backlog.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please share that feature# Is there any alternate that you can suggest on how to analyze and optimize these IUD statements.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Cloud Spanner’s query statistics does not include DML queries (insert, update and delete) and will not have any tables related to those statements.

It is mentioned in these [Google Cloud Viewing query statistics in the console](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-statistics#top_of_page) and [Query statistics tables](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-stats-tables#top_of_page) articles as a note at the top of both pages.